# Make dictionary from list with python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I need to transform a list into dictionary as follows.
The odd elements has the key, and even number elements has the value.

`x = (1,'a',2,'b',3,'c')` -> `{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}`

```
def set(self, val_): 
    i = 0 
    for val in val_: 
        if i == 0: 
            i = 1 
            key = val 
        else: 
            i = 0 
            self.dict[key] = val
```

A better way to get the same results?

### ADDED

```
i = iter(k)
print dict(zip(i,i))
```

seems to be working

Comment: Your method using `zip(i,i)` is equivalent to Ignacio's answer (except  for leaving `i` around afterward).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
dict(x[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(x), 2))
```

Comment: Can you please explain this answer.

Comment: @user2601010, it's just using some elementary building blocks of Python -- calling `dict` (with a sequence of 2-item "pairs") to build a dictionary, slicing a list, a generator expression, and the `range` built-in. Which of these four elementary concepts are unclear to you? (My book "Python in a Nutshell" of course explains all of them, and, many more besides, but, its whole text would not fit in a comment:-).

Answer (score 12):

```
dict(zip(*[iter(val_)] * 2))
```

Answer (score 12):

Here are a couple of ways for **Python3** using dict comprehensions

```
>>> x = (1,'a',2,'b',3,'c')
>>> {k:v for k,v in zip(*[iter(x)]*2)}
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
>>> {x[i]:x[i+1] for i in range(0,len(x),2)}
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
```

Answer (score 11):

```
>>> x=(1,'a',2,'b',3,'c')
>>> dict(zip(x[::2],x[1::2]))
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
```

Comment: Using timeit module, this seems to be fastest method also, so far anyway :)

Comment: Correction, gnibbler's dict comps are both faster on my system (2.58us,3.51us), and mine got slower on Python3.1.2 (4.75us vs. Python2.6.5 4us).

Answer (score 4):

```
x = (1,'a',2,'b',3,'c') 
d = dict(x[n:n+2] for n in xrange(0, len(x), 2))
print d
```