# How can you convert a list of poorly formed data pairs into a dict?

Tags: python

I'd like to take a string containing tuples that are not well separated and convert them into a dictionary.

s = "banana 4 apple 2 orange 4"

d = {'banana':'4', 'apple':'2', 'orange':'4'}

I'm running into a problem because the space is used to separate the values as well as the pairs. What's the right trick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>> s = "banana 4 apple 2 orange 4"
>> lst = s.split()
>> dict(zip(lst[::2], lst[1::2]))
```

Answer (score 5):

Simplistic but serves the solution here:

Use split()

```
>>> s = "banana 4 apple 2 orange 4"
>>> s.split()
['banana', '4', 'apple', '2', 'orange', '4']
>>>
```

Group them ( Some error checks required here)

```
>>> k = [(x[t], x[t+1]) for t in range(0, len(x) -1, 2)]
>>> k
[('banana', '4'), ('apple', '2'), ('orange', '4')]
>>>
```

Create a dictionary out of it

```
>>> dict(k)
{'orange': '4', 'banana': '4', 'apple': '2'}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `.split()`, [get the elements 2 at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597166/make-dictionary-from-list-with-python), and pass it to `dict()`.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand you, it doesn't work that way.  You mean like this (which doesn't work)?  dict('foo 1 bar 2 baz 3'.split())

Comment: @Sean: No, you have to get the elements 2 at a time (Hint: follow the link).

Answer (score -1):

I don't know python but it should be possible to convert the string into an array , then iterate thru the array to create a dictionary by alternating name & value.

Comment: I was thinking you were going to have to split it by character and take the modulo of every third EBCDIC character value. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: not knowing python, i didn't mention any specific method, but the logic remains... split() returns an Array. Not sure what the -1 is for.