# Convert [key1,val1,key2,val2] to a dict?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Let's say I have a list `a` in Python whose entries conveniently map to a dictionary. Each even element represents the key to the dictionary, and the following odd element is the value

for example,

```
a = ['hello','world','1','2']
```

and I'd like to convert it to a dictionary `b`, where

```
b['hello'] = 'world'
b['1'] = '2'
```

What is the syntactically cleanest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make dictionary from list with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597166/make-dictionary-from-list-with-python)

Answer (score 307, accepted):

```
b = dict(zip(a[::2], a[1::2]))
```

If `a` is large, you will probably want to do something like the following, which doesn't make any temporary lists like the above.

```
from itertools import izip
i = iter(a)
b = dict(izip(i, i))
```

In Python 3 you could also use a dict comprehension, but ironically I think the simplest way to do it will be with `range()` and `len()`, which would normally be a code smell.

```
b = {a[i]: a[i+1] for i in range(0, len(a), 2)}
```

So the `iter()/izip()` method is still probably the most Pythonic in Python 3, although as EOL notes in a comment, `zip()` is already lazy in Python 3 so you don't need `izip()`.

```
i = iter(a)
b = dict(zip(i, i))
```

In Python 3.8 and later you can write this on one line using the "walrus" operator (`:=`):

```
b = dict(zip(i := iter(a), i))
```

Otherwise you'd need to use a semicolon to get it on one line.

Comment: … or simply `zip(i, i)`, in Python 3, since `zip()` now returns an iterator.

Comment: Note that Python 2.7.3 also has dict comprehension

Comment: or simple like following ({'abc': a, 'def' : b} for a, b in zip(list1, list2))

Answer (score 69):

#### Simple answer

Another option (courtesy of [Alex Martelli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95810/alex-martelli) - [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2597178/104264)):

```
dict(x[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(x), 2))
```

---

#### Related note

If you have this:

```
a = ['bi','double','duo','two']
```

and you want this (each element of the list keying a given value (2 in this case)):

```
{'bi':2,'double':2,'duo':2,'two':2}
```

you can use:

```
>>> dict((k,2) for k in a)
{'double': 2, 'bi': 2, 'two': 2, 'duo': 2}
```

Comment: Is this for Python 3 only?

Comment: use `fromkeys`.

```>>> dict.fromkeys(a, 2)
{'bi': 2, 'double': 2, 'duo': 2, 'two': 2}
```

Comment: This is doing something else than what the question is asking.

Comment: for some reason `dict.fromkeys()` is making every key's value to be duplicated ( like the items i gave are all "linked" or pointing to the same place in memory )
try: `a = dict.fromkeys(['op1', 'op2'], {})` and then `a["op1"] = 3` you'll see that also `a["op2"]` was populated

Answer (score 19):

You can use a dict comprehension for this pretty easily:

```
a = ['hello','world','1','2']

my_dict = {item : a[index+1] for index, item in enumerate(a) if index % 2 == 0}
```

This is equivalent to the for loop below:

```
my_dict = {}
for index, item in enumerate(a):
    if index % 2 == 0:
        my_dict[item] = a[index+1]
```

Answer (score 17):

Something i find pretty cool, which is that if your list is only 2 items long:

```
ls = ['a', 'b']
dict([ls])
>>> {'a':'b'}
```

Remember, dict accepts any iterable containing an iterable where each item in the iterable must itself be an iterable with exactly two objects.

Comment: quick and simple one, just to add if the list contains more than two items then use dict(ls) instead of dict([ls]). for e.g. if ls=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] then dict(ls)

Comment: Nice & sleek. **'each item in the iterable must itself be an iterable with exactly two objects.'** is the key fact here.

Comment: This really deserves more upvotes, half the answers above are the same and just say to use zip...

Answer (score 5):

May not be the most pythonic, but

```
>>> b = {}
>>> for i in range(0, len(a), 2):
        b[a[i]] = a[i+1]
```

Comment: read about [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Comment: enumerate doesn't let you specify a step size, but you could use `for i, key in enumerate(a[::2]):`. Still unpythonic since the dict constructor can do most of the work here for you

Comment: @SilentGhost, gnibbler: thanks so much for broadening my horizons! I'll be sure to incorporate it as much as possible in the future!

Comment: @gnibbler: Could you explain a little more about how the `for i, key in enumerate(a[::2]):` approach might work? The resulting pair values would be `0 hello` and `1 1`, and it's unclear to me how to use them to produce `{'hello':'world', '1':'2'}`.

Comment: @martineau, you are correct. I think i must have meant `enumerate(a)[::2]`

Answer (score 4):

You can do it pretty fast without creating extra arrays, so this will work even for very large arrays:

```
dict(izip(*([iter(a)]*2)))
```

If you have a generator `a`, even better:

```
dict(izip(*([a]*2)))
```

Here's the rundown:

```
iter(h)    #create an iterator from the array, no copies here
[]*2       #creates an array with two copies of the same iterator, the trick
izip(*())  #consumes the two iterators creating a tuple
dict()     #puts the tuples into key,value of the dictionary
```

Comment: this will make a dictionary with equal key and value pairs (`{'hello':'hello','world':'world','1':'1','2':'2'}`)

Comment: Nope, all work just fine.

Please read more carefully. It says: "If you have a generator a..."

If you don't have a generator, just use the first line. The second one is an alternative that would be useful if you have a generator instead of a list, as one would most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it like this (string to list conversion here, then conversion to a dictionary)

```
    string_list = """
    Hello World
    Goodbye Night
    Great Day
    Final Sunset
    """.split()

    string_list = dict(zip(string_list[::2],string_list[1::2]))

    print string_list
```

Answer (score 1):

I am also very much interested to have a one-liner for this conversion, as far such a list is the default initializer for hashed in Perl.

Exceptionally comprehensive answer is given in this thread -

- [python convert list to dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900955/python-convert-list-to-dictionary)

Mine one I am newbie in Python), using [Python 2.7 Generator Expressions](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions), would be:

`dict((a[i], a[i + 1]) for i in range(0, len(a) - 1, 2))`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is pythonic, but seems to work

```
def alternate_list(a):
   return a[::2], a[1::2]

key_list,value_list = alternate_list(a)
b = dict(zip(key_list,value_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

```
  >>> d2 = dict([('one',1), ('two', 2), ('three', 3)])
  >>> d2
      {'three': 3, 'two': 2, 'one': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this approach save the keys and values in different list and then use dict method

```
data=['test1', '1', 'test2', '2', 'test3', '3', 'test4', '4']

keys=[]
values=[]
for i,j in enumerate(data):
    if i%2==0:
        keys.append(j)
    else:
        values.append(j)

print(dict(zip(keys,values)))
```

output:

```
{'test3': '3', 'test1': '1', 'test2': '2', 'test4': '4'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{x: a[a.index(x)+1] for x in a if a.index(x) % 2 ==0}

result : {'hello': 'world', '1': '2'}
```