# Convert list into a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
l = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

I want to convert this list to a dictionary like:

```
d = {"a": "b", "c": "d", "e": ""}
```

So basically, the evens will be keys whereas the odds will be values. I know that I can do it in a "non-pythonic" way such as a for loop with if statements but I believe that there should be a more "pythonic" way to accomplish this. So, I appreciate any help :)

Comment: To have list members each be its own `key` and `value`: `dict(zip(list, list))`.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Using the usual [grouper recipe](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes), you could do:

**Python 2:**

```
d = dict(itertools.izip_longest(*[iter(l)] * 2, fillvalue=""))
```

**Python 3:**

```
d = dict(itertools.zip_longest(*[iter(l)] * 2, fillvalue=""))
```

Comment: You could also do it as `d = dict(itertools.izip_longest(l[::2], l[1::2], fillvalue=''))`, or in Python 3 `d = dict(itertools.zip_longest(l[::2], l[1::2], fillvalue=''))`. Your version works just fine, but could be slightly confusing to those who don't realize that `[iter(l)] * 2` creates a list containing two references to _the same iterator_. (`[iter(l)]*2` -> `[<list_iterator object at 0x01383FD0>, <list_iterator object at 0x01383FD0>]`)

Comment: @JAB: Since the grouper recipe is quite common, I don't see enough benefit of your approach to justify creating two copies of `l` (using `l[::2]` and `l[1::2]`).

Comment: Hm, I'd always assumed slices were views of an object, not actual copies, due to the usage of `del x[:1]`, `x[:] = [2, 3]`, etc. as operations on mutable sequences as well as the fact that numpy implements array slices as views, but as that doesn't actually seem to be the case I suppose the more efficient method would be `d = dict(izip_longest(islice(l, 0, None, 2), islice(l, 1, None, 2), fillvalue=''))`. I wonder if there's been a feature request for that submitted yet, and what the response was if so...

Answer (score 173):

If you are still thinking what the! You would not be alone, its actually not that complicated really, let me explain.

## How to turn a list into a dictionary using built-in functions only

We want to turn the following list into a dictionary using the odd entries (counting from 1) as keys mapped to their consecutive even entries.

```
l = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

#### dict()

To create a dictionary we can use the built in `dict` function for [Mapping Types](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) as per the manual the following methods are supported.

```
dict(one=1, two=2)
dict({'one': 1, 'two': 2})
dict(zip(('one', 'two'), (1, 2)))
dict([['two', 2], ['one', 1]])
```

The last option suggests that we supply a list of lists with 2 values or `(key, value)` tuples, so we want to turn our sequential list into:

```
l = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e",]]
```

We are also introduced to the `zip` function, [one of the built-in functions](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) which the manual explains:

> returns a list of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the arguments

In other words if we can turn our list into two lists `a, c, e` and `b, d` then `zip` will do the rest.

#### slice notation

[Slicings](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#slicings) which we see used with [Strings](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) and also further on in the [List section](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) which mainly uses the **range** or **short slice** notation but this is what the **long slice** notation looks like and what we can accomplish with **step**:

```
>>> l[::2]
['a', 'c', 'e']

>>> l[1::2]
['b', 'd']

>>> zip(['a', 'c', 'e'], ['b', 'd'])
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]

>>> dict(zip(l[::2], l[1::2]))
{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}
```

Even though this is the simplest way to understand the mechanics involved there is a downside because slices are new list objects each time, as can be seen with this cloning example:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]

>>> b is a
True

>>> b = a[:]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]

>>> b is a
False
```

Even though b looks like a they are two separate objects now and this is why we prefer to use the [grouper recipe](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) instead.

#### grouper recipe

Although the grouper is explained as part of the itertools module it works perfectly fine with the basic functions too.

Some serious voodoo right? =) But actually nothing more than a bit of syntax sugar for spice, the grouper recipe is accomplished by the following expression.

```
*[iter(l)]*2
```

Which more or less translates to two arguments of the same iterator wrapped in a list, if that makes any sense. Lets break it down to help shed some light.

#### zip for shortest

```
>>> l*2
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

>>> [l]*2
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']]

>>> [iter(l)]*2
[<listiterator object at 0x100486450>, <listiterator object at 0x100486450>]

>>> zip([iter(l)]*2)
[(<listiterator object at 0x1004865d0>,),(<listiterator object at 0x1004865d0>,)]

>>> zip(*[iter(l)]*2)
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]

>>> dict(zip(*[iter(l)]*2))
{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}
```

As you can see the addresses for the two iterators remain the same so we are working with the same iterator which zip then first gets a key from and then a value and a key and a value every time stepping the same iterator to accomplish what we did with the slices much more productively.

You would accomplish very much the same with the following which carries a smaller **What the?** factor perhaps.

```
>>> it = iter(l)     
>>> dict(zip(it, it))
{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}
```

What about the empty key `e` if you've noticed it has been missing from all the examples which is because `zip` picks the shortest of the two arguments, so what are we to do.

Well one solution might be adding an empty value to odd length lists, you may choose to use `append` and an `if` statement which would do the trick, albeit slightly boring, right?

```
>>> if len(l) % 2:
...     l.append("")

>>> l
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', '']

>>> dict(zip(*[iter(l)]*2))
{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': ''}
```

Now before you shrug away to go type `from itertools import izip_longest` you may be surprised to know it is not required, we can accomplish the same, even better IMHO, with the built in functions alone.

#### map for longest

I prefer to use the [map() function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) instead of [izip_longest()](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) which not only uses shorter syntax doesn't require an import but it can assign an actual `None` empty value when required, automagically.

```
>>> l = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
>>> l
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

>>> dict(map(None, *[iter(l)]*2))
{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': None}
```

Comparing performance of the two methods, as pointed out by KursedMetal, it is clear that the itertools module far outperforms the map function on large volumes, as a benchmark against 10 million records show.

```
$ time python -c 'dict(map(None, *[iter(range(10000000))]*2))'
real    0m3.755s
user    0m2.815s
sys     0m0.869s
$ time python -c 'from itertools import izip_longest; dict(izip_longest(*[iter(range(10000000))]*2, fillvalue=None))'
real    0m2.102s
user    0m1.451s
sys     0m0.539s
```

However the cost of importing the module has its toll on smaller datasets with map returning much quicker up to around 100 thousand records when they start arriving head to head.

```
$ time python -c 'dict(map(None, *[iter(range(100))]*2))'
real    0m0.046s
user    0m0.029s
sys     0m0.015s
$ time python -c 'from itertools import izip_longest; dict(izip_longest(*[iter(range(100))]*2, fillvalue=None))'
real    0m0.067s
user    0m0.042s
sys     0m0.021s

$ time python -c 'dict(map(None, *[iter(range(100000))]*2))'
real    0m0.074s
user    0m0.050s
sys     0m0.022s
$ time python -c 'from itertools import izip_longest; dict(izip_longest(*[iter(range(100000))]*2, fillvalue=None))'
real    0m0.075s
user    0m0.047s
sys     0m0.024s
```

See nothing to it! =)

nJoy!

Comment: Python 3 does not suppor `map(None, ...)`, so your solution is limited  to Python 2.X

Comment: Python 3.4.3 supports map(None, ...), e.g. dict(map(None, *[iter(l)]*2)) returns dict(map(None, *[iter(l)]*2)) for l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

Answer (score 21):

I'd go for recursions:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', ' ']
d = dict([(k, v) for k,v in zip (l[::2], l[1::2])])
```

Comment: Why is this recursive?  It looks iterative to me.

Comment: what became dict comprehension https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/

Comment: I think this is enough `dict(zip(l[::2], l[1::2]))`. Worked well for me, Python 3.8.5

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whether it would help you or not but it works to me:

```
l = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
outRes = dict((l[i], l[i+1]) if i+1 < len(l) else (l[i], '') for i in xrange(len(l)))
```

Comment: One note is that +1 is for start at ONE, if yours starts at ZERO, just remove the +1. Worked like a charm for me! Nice one!