# How can I read csv file only after finding a certain pattern with Python?

Tags: python, csv

So I have **several** csv files that represent some data, each of which may have different lines of initial comments

```
table_doi: 10.17182/hepdata.52402.v1/t7
name: Table 7
...
ABS(YRAP), < 0.1
SQRT(S) [GeV], 1960
PT [GEV], PT [GEV] LOW, PT [GEV] HIGH, D2(SIG)/DYRAP/DPT [NB/GEV]
67, 62, 72, 6.68
...
613.5, 527, 700, 1.81E-07
```

I would like to read in only the relevant data and their headers as well, which start from the line

```
PT [GEV], PT [GEV] LOW, PT [GEV] HIGH, D2(SIG)/DYRAP/DPT [NB/GEV]
```

Therefore the strategy I would think of is to find the pattern `PT [GEV]` and start reading from there.

However, I am not sure how to achieve this in Python, could anyone help me on that?

Thank you in advance!

---

By the way, the function I currently have is

```py
import os
import glob
import csv

def read_multicolumn_csv_files_into_dictionary(folderpath, dictionary):
    filepath = folderpath + '*.csv'
    files = sorted(glob.glob(filepath))
    for file in files:
        data_set = file.replace(folderpath, '').replace('.csv', '')
        dictionary[data_set] = {}
        with open(file, 'r') as data_file:
            data_pipe = csv.DictReader(data_file)
            dictionary[data_set]['pt'] = []
            dictionary[data_set]['sigma'] = []
            for row in data_pipe:
                dictionary[data_set]['pt'].append(float(row['PT [GEV]']))
                dictionary[data_set]['sigma'].append(float(row['D2(SIG)/DYRAP/DPT [NB/GEV]']))
    return dictionary
```

which only works if I manually delete those initial comments in the csv files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming every file has a line that startswith `PT [GEV]`:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

...
csvs = []
for file in files:
    with open(file) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            if l.startswith('PT [GEV]'):
                csvs.append(pd.read_csv(file, skiprows = i))
                break
df = pd.concat(csvs)
```

Answer (score 2):

checkout `startswith`. Also, you can find detailed explanation here. https://cmdlinetips.com/2018/01/3-ways-to-read-a-file-and-skip-initial-comments-in-python/

Comment: I have read that webpage before, however, what I am trying to do is to find `PT [GEV]` and read everything beyond that point, while the lines beyond that may not necessarily start with `PT [GEV]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this where it will be searching for the row that contains `PT [GEV]` and if it finds the contains, it will change the `m` to be true and start to append the rest of date  to the list :

```
import csv

contain= 'PT [GEV]'
List=[]
m=false
with open('Users.csv', 'rt') as f:
     reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',') 
     for row in reader:
          for field in row:
              if field == contain:
              m=true
          if m==true:
             List.append(row)
```

Comment: That worked! It would return a list of list, how do you think I could pass it to `csv.DictReader`? Or do you have a better idea manipulating it?

Comment: you can convert the list to dictionary easily see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900955/python-convert-list-to-dictionary

Comment: Thanks, I will try that, sorry for late response.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `file.tell` method to save the file pointer position while you read and skip the lines until you find the header line, at which point you can use the `file.seek` method to reset the file pointer back to the beginning of the header line so that `csv.DictReader` can parse the rest of the file as valid CSV:

```
with open(file, 'r') as data_file:
    while True:
        position = data_file.tell()
        line = next(data_file)
        if line.count(',') == 3: # or whatever condition your header line satisfies
            data_file.seek(position) # reset file pointer to the beginning of the header line
            break
    data_pipe = csv.DictReader(data_file)
    ...
```

Comment: That is a nice way of doing it! I have 20 entries for actual data, so I write `if line.count(',') == 19:` but I am getting back empty dictionary. So I tried to print `line` before the `if` statement and it does seem like the `while` loop is terminated once the program found the actual header line. Do you think the problem comes from passing `data_file` to `data_pipe`?

Answer (score 0):

I would just create a help function to get your csv reader to the first record:

```
def remove_comments_from_file():

    file_name = "super_secret_file.csv"
    file = open(file_name, 'rU')

    csv_read_file = csv.reader(file)        

    for row in csv_read_file:
        if row[0] == "PT [GEV]"
            break

    return csv_read_file
```

Something along those lines, when the csv reader is returned, it will start at your first record (in this example - 67, 62, 72, 6.68)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how do I manipulate on the returned `csv_read_file`? I tried to pass it to the function but it would be recognized as a `NoneType`, then I tried to print it, but the only thing that is showed is `<_csv.reader object at 0x1190d44b0>`.

Comment: By the way, there are some empty lines that could cause problems, so I added a statement `if row != []:` that deals with this.