# How to create dictionary from list

Tags: python

Im new to python so I apologize in advance if this is a bit rudimentary, but given the list:

```
lst = ['user1', 25, 'user2', 10, 'user3', 54]
```

how would I create a dictionary that would be:

```
usr_dict = {'user1': 25, 'user2': 10, 'user3': 54]
```

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900955/python-convert-list-to-dictionary).

But here is a method that is a little easier to understand:

```
usr_dict = {}
for i in range(0, len(lst), 2):
    usr_dict[lst[i]] = lst[i + 1]
```

Comment: ah ok thank you for that. It was the range part I was having trouble with. Much appreciated jdaz

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is a dict comprehension:

`usr_dict = {x[::2]:x[1::2] for x in lst}`