# How to convert the following lists into dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list like this:

```
[['ok.txt', 'hello'], [10, 20], ['first_one', 'second_one'], ['done', 'pending']]
```

I want to convert this list into dictionary like this:

```
{'ok.txt' : ['10', 'first_one', 'done'], 'hello' : ['20', 'second_one', 'pending']}
```

How to do something like this?

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576115/python-list-to-dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the built-in zip function to perform this easily like this:

```
list_of_list = [['ok.txt', 'hello'], [10, 20], ['first_one', 'second_one'], ['done', 'pending']]
dict_from_list = dict(zip(list_of_list[0], zip(*list_of_list[1:])))
```

In this, the interior zip(*list_of_list[1:]) will convert the list of lists from list_of_list(except the first element) to a list of tuples. The tuple is order preserved and is again zipped with the supposed keys to form a list of tuples, which is converted to a proper dictionary through the dict function.

Please note that this will have tuple as data type for the values in the dictionary. As per your example, the one-liner will give:

```
{'ok.txt': (10, 'first_one', 'done'), 'hello': (20, 'second_one', 'pending')}
```

In order to have a list, you have to map the interior zip with the list function.
(i.e) change

```
zip(*list_of_list[1:]) ==> map(list, zip(*list_of_list[1:]))
```

For info about zip function, click [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

Edit: I just noticed that the answer is same as that of the one given by Simon. Simon gave it lot quicker when I was trying the code in terminal and I didn't noticed his answer when I was posting.

Comment: Please give attribution when using other people's code. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
dict(zip(xs[0], zip(*xs[1:])))
```

For lists as values of the dict:

```
dict(zip(xs[0], map(list, zip(*xs[1:]))))
```

Comment: Strictly speaking this won't create lists but tuples.

Comment: the first one is perfect @BurhanKhalid `tuple`s will most likely suffice for OP

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> lis  = [['ok.txt', 'hello'], [10, 20], ['first_one', 'second_one'], ['done', 'pending']]
>>> keys, values = lis[0],lis[1:]
>>> {key:[val[i] for val in values] 
                                  for i,key in enumerate(keys) for val in values}
{'ok.txt': [10, 'first_one', 'done'], 'hello': [20, 'second_one', 'pending']}
```