# Python Best Way to construct Dictionary from Inputs

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to construct a nested dictionary from user inputs.  The only issue is, the user can opt to not enter some of these inputs.  In these cases, I want the dictionary to completely exclude that field.  For Instance:

```
ids = 1234
dmas = 5678
```

I would like the dictionary to look like this:

```
d = {profile:{"dma_targets":dmas, "id":ids}}
```

However, if user decides not to include certain input:

```
ids = None
dmas = 5678
```

I would like the dictionary to look like this:

```
d = {profile:{"dma_targets":dmas}}
```

I'm a bit stuck here, and it seems like a very simple thing, as it would be easy to do if I wanted a list instead of a dict.  One of the problems I'm running into is:

```
x = "dma_targets":dmas
```

is not a valid object, so I'm having a hard time constructing the pieces of this, then adding them into the dictionary.  Thanks so much!

Comment: `x = "dma_targets":dmas` is not valid input, but `x = {"dma_targets":dmas}` is... why not try that? I guess I'm not totally clear what you're trying to achieve. If you can get it into a list, why not convert the list to a dict? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576115/python-list-to-dictionary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about a little [dict comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)?

```
fkeys = ['dma_targets', 'ids']
fvals = [5678, None]
d = {'profile': {k:v for (k,v) in zip(fkeys, fvals) if v is not None}}
```

which yields `d` as

```
{'profile': {'dma_targets': 5678}}
```

Comment: You'll want to change `if v` to `if v is not None` if 0 is a valid value.

Comment: This is perfect. It just completely slipped my mind to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```py
d = {profile:{}}
if ids:
    d['profile']['ids'] = ids
if dmas:
    d['profile']['dma_targets'] = dmas
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want a nested dictionary with different types (python allows you to do this).

```
from collections import defaultdict
d  = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
d['a']['b'].append('bla')
d[15] = 15
```