# Converting a list from a .txt file into a dictionary

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary

Ok, I've tried all the methods in [Convert a list to a dictionary in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576115/python-list-to-dictionary), but I can't seem to get this to work right.  I'm trying to convert a list that I've made from a .txt file into a dictionary.  So far my code is:

```
import os.path
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import csv


window = Tk()
window.title("Please Choose a .txt File")
fileName = askopenfilename()

classInfoList = []
classRoster = {}
with open(fileName, newline = '') as listClasses:
    for line in csv.reader(listClasses):
        classInfoList.append(line)
```

The .txt file is in the format:
professor
class
students

An example would be:
Professor White
Chem 101
Jesse Pinkman, Brandon Walsh, Skinny Pete

The output I desire would be a dictionary with professors as the keys, and then the class and list of students for the values.

```
OUTPUT: 
{"Professor White": ["Chem 101", [Jesse Pinkman, Brandon Walsh, Skinny Pete]]}
```

However, when I tried the things in the above post, I kept getting errors.

What can I do here?

Thanks

Comment: How are the fields in `Professor White Chem 101 Jesse Pinkman, Brandon Walsh, Skinny Pete` separated?

Comment: [['Professor White'], ['Chem 101'], ['Jesse Pinkman', ' Skinny Pete', ' Brandon Mayhew', ' Marti Nansen', ' Todd Schultz'], [], ['Professor Draven'], ['Crim 210'], ['Saul Goodman', ' Mike Ehrmantrau', ' Jesse Pinkman', ' Bruce Wayne', ' Gus Fring'], [],...etc.  

I need to get rid of th extra instances of [], too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data making up your dictionary is on consecutive lines, you will have to process three lines at once. You can use the `next()` method on the file handle like this:

```
output = {}
input_file = open('file1')
for line in input_file:
    key = line.strip()
    value = [next(input_file).strip()]
    value.append(next(input_file).split(','))
    output[key] = value
input_file.close()
```

This would give you:

```
{'Professor White': ['Chem 101',
                     ['Jesse Pinkman, Brandon Walsh, Skinny Pete']]}
```

Comment: It's separated by enter, so professors on on the first line, class second line, students third line, repeat.

Comment: @Blackwell In that case you don't even need the csv module. Check my updated answer

Comment: Indeed that worked.  I'll have to research how next works.  Thank you.

Comment: When you read a file, the lines in the file is returned as an iterator. `next()` is a method on any iterator. More here - https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next