# List of classes to dict

Tags: python, iterable

I have a list with a bunch of `People` classes. I want to get each `People.name` atribute (via `get_name` method) so it becomes the key for that instance into a dict.

Example:

```
people_list = [person1, person2, person3, person4]
# Becomes:
people_dict = {'John': person1, 'Mary': person2, 'Mike': person3, 'Jay Z': person4]
```

Of course, this can be easily achieved with a proper loop, but I was looking for a pythonic, efficient way of doing this conversion.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576115/python-list-to-dictionary), and tried its accepted answer with a little change:

```
from itertools import izip
iterable = iter(people_list)
people_dict = dict(izip(iterable.get_name, iterable))
```

Of course, this does not work, because `iterable` is not an instance of `People` class, but a `listiterator` which does not have a method called `get_code`. But I guess it is clear what I'm trying to achieve.

So, any idea? I'm currently using python 2.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension to produce your dictionary:

```
people_dict = {p.get_name(): p for p in people_list}
```

This produces a key-value pair for each entry in `people_list`, where the key is taken from the `p.get_name()` method call.

You could do it with the `dict()` call too, in which case you'd use a generator expression producing key-value pairs as tuples:

```
people_dict = dict((p.get_name(), p) for p in people_list)
```

The latter is the syntax you'd have to use on older Python versions, as dictionary comprehensions were only added to Python 2.7 and up.

`zip()` (or `itertools.izip()`) would only be useful if you had *separate* iterables with the keys and values, and needed to pair those up before creating a dictionary. You don't have that here; you have a single list of objects which are directly capable of providing the keys.

Answer (score 1):

You can make dictionaries using comps the same way you would make a list.

```
{element.get_name(): element for element in people_list}
```