# How to convert a list to dict using python

Tags: python

i have a list looks like this

```
 [(u'name1', (47.5320299939, 7.70498245944), (47.5321349987, 7.70499587048), (47.5319710886, 7.70484834899), (47.5320299939, 7.70498245944)),(u'name2', (47.5320299939, 7.70498245944), (47.5321349987, 7.70499587048), (47.5319710886, 7.70484834899), (47.5320299939, 7.70498245944))]
```

i want to convert the list as dict something like this

```
{'name1': (47.5320299939, 7.70498245944), (47.5321349987, 7.70499587048), (47.5319710886, 7.70484834899), (47.5320299939, 7.70498245944)}
```

i want to do it in python. can anyone help.

Comment: That's not a valid dictionary; did you mean for the tuples to be gathered in to one list value?

Comment: What happened to `name2` in the input?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: List to Dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576115/python-list-to-dictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dictionary comprehension can do this:

```
{item[0]: item[1:] for item in inputlist}
```

As your input elements are tuples, your output values are tuples too:

```
>>> inputlist = [(u'name1', (47.5320299939, 7.70498245944), (47.5321349987, 7.70499587048), (47.5319710886, 7.70484834899), (47.5320299939, 7.70498245944)),(u'name2', (47.5320299939, 7.70498245944), (47.5321349987, 7.70499587048), (47.5319710886, 7.70484834899), (47.5320299939, 7.70498245944))]
>>> {item[0]: item[1:] for item in inputlist}
{u'name2': ((47.5320299939, 7.70498245944), (47.5321349987, 7.70499587048), (47.5319710886, 7.70484834899), (47.5320299939, 7.70498245944)), u'name1': ((47.5320299939, 7.70498245944), (47.5321349987, 7.70499587048), (47.5319710886, 7.70484834899), (47.5320299939, 7.70498245944))}
>>> pprint({item[0]: item[1:] for item in inputlist})
{u'name1': ((47.5320299939, 7.70498245944),
            (47.5321349987, 7.70499587048),
            (47.5319710886, 7.70484834899),
            (47.5320299939, 7.70498245944)),
 u'name2': ((47.5320299939, 7.70498245944),
            (47.5321349987, 7.70499587048),
            (47.5319710886, 7.70484834899),
            (47.5320299939, 7.70498245944))}
```

Comment: @@Martinjn Pieters: Thanks Martijn. It worked. This is what i want.