# Python: convert list into dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list like below

```
['position_Matrix position1', 'postal_code post10']
```

I was trying to make a dictionary based on this list and as expected below

```
{position_Matrix:position1, postal_code:post10}
```

Tried with below code and it doesn't work. Can someone help on this?

```
dict(map(lambda x: x.split(" "), alias.split(",")))
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean. Please add your traceback to your post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: List to Dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576115/python-list-to-dictionary)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `alias` is your list, the issue is that you're trying to split a list.
You almost had it right, just remove the `split`. This will work:

```
dict(map(lambda x: x.split(" "), alias))
```

Comment: `dict(x.split() for x in alias)` is likely faster if that matters in the slightest (it's somewhat inefficient to map with lambdas).

Comment: @Morgan Thank you Very much. This is what i am looking for

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a dict comprehension:

```
d = {x.split()[0]: x.split()[1] for x in some_list}
#equivalent and more efficient
d = dict(map(str.split, some_list)) # this would be my preferred solution
#another equivalent (ugly)
d = dict(zip(*[y.split() for y in x]))
```