# Python: Python:Sort values in dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set

I have

```
x = {2:[40,30],3:[24,16],4:[30,2],5:[0,80],6:[19,8]}
```

and I need to sort dictionary based on the 1st item in the value 
so my result should be

```
{2:[40,30],4:[30,2],3:[24,16],6:[19,8],5:[0,80]}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: List to Dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576115/python-list-to-dictionary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply pass it into [`dict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict):

```
>>> dict([(2, [40, 30]), (4, [30, 2])])
{2: [40, 30], 4: [30, 2]}
```

Dictionaries don't care what order their values are in:

```
>>> {'one': 1, 'two': 2} == {'two': 2, 'one': 1}
True
```

If you want to maintain order, you can use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> OrderedDict([(2, [40, 30]), (4, [30, 2])])
OrderedDict([(2, [40, 30]), (4, [30, 2])])
```

Comment: but if i have x = [(4, [30, 2]), (2, [40, 30])] on calling dict(x) i'll get {2: [40, 30], 4: [30, 2]} but i want answer in such a way that order should not be changed, i should get { 4: [30, 2], 2: [40, 30]}

Comment: @SagarR, I have added an example using `collections.OrderedDict`, which cares about the order of its elements (unlike `dict`).

Comment: is this possible if i have x = {2:[40,30],3:[24,16],4:[30,2],5:[0,80],6:[19,8]} and i need to sort dictionary based on the 1st item in the value so my result should be {2:[40,30],4:[30,2],3:[24,16],6:[19,8],5:[0,80]}

Comment: @SagarR, you keep changing the rules. First you asked how to create a `dict`, and two people showed you. Then you changed your question to ask how to maintain order, and I updated my answer and you also got a _new_ answer talking about `OrderedDict`. Now you are asking how to _change_ the order based on the value being stored. Please make sure you know what you actually want and include those details in your question. I am leaving my answer as-is since I have answered two of your questions correctly. Feel free to ask a _new_ question with your new rules.

Comment: first i had x = {2:[40,30],3:[24,16],4:[30,2],5:[0,80],6:[19,8]} then i called sorted(x.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True) it gave me [(2, [40, 30]), (4, [30, 2]), (3, [24, 16]), (6, [19, 8]), (5, [0, 80])] so i asked a question to convert to dict in a same order...

Comment: @SagarR, so put that into `collections.OrderedDict`.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is using `dict`

```
d = dict(x)
```

Since your `list` is already in the right format to be easily converted to `Dictionary`, that is, you already have a `key-value` tuple pair as your list elements.

Comment: but if i have x = [(4, [30, 2]), (2, [40, 30])] on calling dict(x) i'll get {2: [40, 30], 4: [30, 2]} but i want answer in such a way that order should not be changed, i should get { 4: [30, 2], 2: [40, 30]}

Comment: @SagarR unfortunately, `Dictionary` does not have concept of `Order`. `Order` is concept in `list`. Dictionary runs with `Key-Value` pair concept. You use key and you get the value, that is why it is unordered. Another reason is that it is done this way to gain some performance benefit internally. You need to find the right tool for your use. If you need it to be ordered, please use `List`, don't use `Dict`. if you need key value pair, use `dict`. If you need both, then you may create both - something along that line

Comment: is this possible if i have x = {2:[40,30],3:[24,16],4:[30,2],5:[0,80],6:[19,8]} and i need to sort dictionary based on the 1st item in the value so my result should be {2:[40,30],4:[30,2],3:[24,16],6:[19,8],5:[0,80]}

Comment: @SagarR to keep it ordered, you *can't* use dictionary. You may want to look int [OrderedDict](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/python-dictionary-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared) though.

Comment: @SagarR you mean the `list`, `dict`, and `OrderedDict`? great! :) find your *right* tool, that is the key...

Answer (score 1):

You weren't explicit in your question, but from your comments on other answers you want to preserve the order of the list in dictionary form. A standard dictionary is inherently unordered, however, you can use an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

x =  [(4, [30, 2]), (2, [40, 30])]
d = dict(x)
print(d)
# {2: [40, 30], 4: [30, 2]}

d = OrderedDict(x)
print(d)
# OrderedDict([(4, [30, 2]), (2, [40, 30])])
```

This preserves the keys in order of addition to the dictionary.