# Convert list to list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two python lists like the following:

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "guava", "grapes"]  
colour = ["red", "yellow", "green", "black"]
```

I wish to convert them into a dictionary of the following format:

```
dictionary = [{"fruit":"apple", "colour":"red"},{"fruit":"banana", "colour":"yellow"}...]
```

Comment: consider providing further details like the code you've already tried etc :)

Comment: Very similary to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576115/convert-a-list-to-a-dictionary-in-python?rq=1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Zip your fruit and colour lists together using the [`zip()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip), and build a new dictionary from each pair:

```
[{'fruit': f, 'colour': c} for f, c in zip(fruits, colour)]
```

This uses a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to create the list output from a loop.

Demo:

```
>>> fruits = ["apple", "banana", "guava", "grapes"]
>>> colour = ["red", "yellow", "green", "black"]
>>> [{'fruit': f, 'colour': c} for f, c in zip(fruits, colour)]
[{'colour': 'red', 'fruit': 'apple'}, {'colour': 'yellow', 'fruit': 'banana'}, {'colour': 'green', 'fruit': 'guava'}, {'colour': 'black', 'fruit': 'grapes'}]
```

Comment: As always a good answer of you! But keep in mind that even Python beginners might not understand zipping of lists or for loops with several variable assignments in a list comprehension...

Comment: @linusg: I'm here for follow-up comments, there usually are SO questions and documentation we can point to.

Answer (score 0):

A good solution I found is to use an external CSV file to manage your dictionary
for example the dict.csv is the directry of the csv file

```
import csv
import os

dictionary = os.getcwd() +  r'\dict.csv'
with open(dictionary, mode='r') as infile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile)
        mydict = {rows[0]:rows[1] for rows in reader}
```

and in the csv file can have first column as fruits second column as color. Easy to modify and manage