# Making dictionary from two lists

Tags: python, django

I have two lists

```
l1 = ['cat','dog']
l2= [1,2]
```

Now I want to make a dictionary like this:

```
dict { {'name':cat,'id'=1}{'name':dog,'id'=2}}
```

I am using `zip` but that's not fulfilling my requirement.

Comment: refer this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576115/convert-a-list-to-a-dictionary-in-python

Answer (score 6):

```
result = [{'name': name, 'id': id} for (name, id) in zip(l1, l2)]
```

It doesn't make sense for the container all the individual dicts are in to be a dict as well (unless you want to key it on, say, id).

Answer (score 3):

If you have a lot of keys and you don't want to create dict comprehension and declare what goes where.

```
l1 = ['cat','dog']
l2= [1,2]
[dict(zip(['name', 'id'], el)) for el in zip(l1,l2)]
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'cat'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'dog'}]
```