# Convert List to Dict

Tags: python

How do I convert  this LIST data structure to DICTIONARY. I want it in a key/value format.

```
['FREQ=WEEKLY', 'INTERVAL=2', 'UNTIL=20170511T050000Z', 'BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA,SU', 'RDATE:20170224T060000Z', 'EXDATE:20170228T060000Z']
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a list to a dictionary in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576115/convert-a-list-to-a-dictionary-in-python)

Comment: So some of your elements are deliminated by `=` but others by `:`?

Comment: your list didn't have similar elements, some have = and other have :, so on which  symbol you need to split.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: TigerhawkT3, Thanks for that tip. I should have posted a code. I will do that next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just split the string and put them in dict:

```
l=['FREQ=WEEKLY', 'INTERVAL=2', 'UNTIL=20170511T050000Z', 'BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA,SU', 'RDATE:20170224T060000Z', 'EXDATE:20170228T060000Z']
d={}
for i in l:
    if "=" in i:
        d[i.split("=")[0]]=i.split("=")[1]
    elif ":" in i:
        d[i.split(":")[0]] = i.split(":")[1]
    else:
        pass
print d
```

Output:

```
{'BYDAY': 'MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA,SU', 'INTERVAL': '2', u'RDATE': '20170224T060000Z', 'EXDATE': '20170228T060000Z', 'FREQ': 'WEEKLY', 'UNTIL': '20170511T050000Z'}
```

Comment: I think you want `str.partition`

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample code with work with both symbols `=` and `:`:-

```
a = ['FREQ=WEEKLY', 'INTERVAL=2', 'UNTIL=20170511T050000Z', 'BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA,SU', 'RDATE:20170224T060000Z', 'EXDATE:20170228T060000Z']


print {spi[0]:spi[1] for spi in [item.split("=") if "=" in item else item.split(":") for item in a]}

output: {'BYDAY': 'MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA,SU', 'EXDATE': '20170228T060000Z', 'FREQ': 'WEEKLY', 'INTERVAL': '2','RDATE': '20170224T060000Z','UNTIL': '20170511T050000Z'}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to split on multiple delimiters is probably `re.split`.

```
import re
data = ['FREQ=WEEKLY', 'INTERVAL=2', 'UNTIL=20170511T050000Z', 'BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA,SU', 'RDATE:20170224T060000Z', 'EXDATE:20170228T060000Z']
result = dict(re.split('=|:', line, 1) for line in data)
```