# Converting list to dict python

Tags: python, dictionary

Given a list:

```
source = [{'A':123},{'B':234},{'C':345}]
```

I need a dict from this list in the format:

```
newDict  = {'A':123,'B':234,'C':345}
```

What is the syntactically cleanest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a list to a dictionary in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576115/convert-a-list-to-a-dictionary-in-python)

Comment: Certainly not the most "syntactically clean" way, but somewhat fun: `reduce(lambda d, cur: d.update(cur) or d, source, {})`

Comment: What if you have a list `[{'A': 123}, {'A': 456}]`? Should the result be `{'A': 123}` or `{'A': 456}`?

Comment: if source = [{'A':123},{'B':234},{'C':345},{'A':123}]  Then we have issues. Forming dict duplicate keys not possible. Complete data cannot be analyzed in that case

Comment: I'd rename the question along the lines of "merging a list of dict entries into one dict"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a dict-comprehension:

```
>>> l = [{'A':123},{'B':234},{'C':345}]
>>> d = {k: v for dct in l for k, v in dct.items()}
>>> d
{'A': 123, 'B': 234, 'C': 345}
```

However it's probably opinion-based if that's the "syntactically cleanest way" but I like it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an additional approach, provided here to give you a flavor for how Python implements the functional programming technique called [reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)), via the `reduce()` function.  In Python 3, [`reduce()` is in the functools package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce).  In Python 2, [`reduce()` is a built-in function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce).  I use Python 3 in the example below:

```
from functools import reduce    # don't import if you are using Python 2

def updater(dict_orig, dict_add):
    dict_orig.update(dict_add)
    return dict_orig

new_dict = reduce(updater, l, dict())
```

The first argument to `reduce()` is the function to operate on the iterable, the second is the iterable itself (your list `l`), and the third is the optional initializer object to put at the beginning of the `list` to reduce.

Each step of the reduction requires an object to be operated on: namely, the result of the previous step. But [`dict.update()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) does not return anything, so we need the `updater()` function above, which performs the update and then returns the `dict` being updated, thus providing the required object for the next step.  Were it not for `dict.update()` not having a return value, this would all be a one-liner.

Because `dict.update()` operates directly on the original `dict`, we need that optional empty `dict()` initializer object to start out the reduction - without it, the first `dict` in your original `l` list would be modified.

For all these reasons, I like @MSeifert's dict-comprehension approach much better, but I posted this anyway just to illustrate Python reduction for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you use it often, you might want to define a `merge` function, which you can then pass to `reduce` :

```
from functools import reduce # Needed for Python3
source = [{'A':123},{'B':234},{'C':345}]

def merge(a,b):
    d = a.copy()
    d.update(b)
    return d

print(reduce(merge, source))
#=> {'A': 123, 'C': 345, 'B': 234}
```