# Map two lists generated in NLTK to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nltk

I am working with two lists generated by NLTK's [PlaintextCorpusReader](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.corpus.reader.html#nltk.corpus.reader.plaintext.PlaintextCorpusReader) and I would like to combine them into a single dictionary.

The keys for the dictionary should be the sentences in the corpus, which I've extracted using PlaintextCorpusReader's `.sents()`. The values should be the fileids of where each sentence is located in the corpus, which I've extracted using `.fileids()`.

The `.fileids()` come back as strings, e.g.

```
['R_v_Cole_2007.txt', 'R_v_Sellick_2005.txt']
```

The `.sents()` come back as `list(list(str))`, e.g.

```
[[u'1', u'.'], [u'The', u'Registrar', u'has', u'referred', u'to', u'this', u'Court', u'two', u'applications', u'for', u'permission', u'to', u'appeal', u'against', u'conviction', u'to', u'be', u'heard', u'together', u'.'], ...]
```

I've tried a range of things, mainly from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576115/convert-a-list-to-a-dictionary-in-python) on a similar issue, but everything I try results in the following error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Where am I going wrong?

The code I'm working with to get the stuff I want for the dictionary is as follows:

```
corpus_root = '/Users/danielhoadley/Documents/Python/NLTK/text/'
wordlists = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root, '.*')

dictionary = {}

values = wordlists.fileids()
keys = wordlists.sents()

## How do I get the keys and values into a dictionary from here?
```

Comment: You can't use lists as keys for a dictionary, loop through the result from `sents()` and turn them into tuples.

Comment: @NickA thanks, Nick. It may be the lateness of the hour, but I'm struggling to construct this loop. I'm trying: for item in sents(): key = tupple(tupple(item)). Are you able to steer me further in the right direction?

Comment: You didn't make it very clear what you want mapped to what.  Do you want to look up a word to see which file it was in? What if both files have u'this'? Does the first list have N filenames, and the second list has N lists of tokens which appear in that file? Maybe you should post the complete dict you want from a small sample input. (also post code for your attempt to do it)

Comment: `for item in sents: key = tuple(item)`