# I have a list how to make dictionary

Tags: python, list

I have a list like `['ASDE','apple','ASWED','orange']`

how I can make a dictionary like
`{"ASDE":"apple","ASWED":"orange"}`?

Comment: Please add more tag like programming language for example python, java and etc.

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576115/convert-a-list-to-a-dictionary-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer. Since you did not really put much effort into your question, I won't bother explaining.

```
>>> l = ['ASDE','apple','ASWED','orange']
>>> dict(zip(*[iter(l)]*2))
{'ASWED': 'orange', 'ASDE': 'apple'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Python, here's a version that uses a for loop:

```
myList=['ASDE', 'apple', 'ASWED', 'orange']
myDictionary={}
counter=0
for item in myList:
    if counter %2 == 0:
        myDictionary[item]='new'
        indexItem=item
    else:
        myDictionary[indexItem]=item
    counter+=1
print(myDictionary)
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is we can iterate through list with step of 2 instead of 1 and store items as key and value:

```
my_dict = {my_list[index]: my_list[index+1] for index in range(0, len(my_list), 2)}
my_dict
```

Output:

```
{'ASDE': 'apple', 'ASWED': 'orange'}
```