# Turning a list into a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Im trying to turn a list into a dictionary. so say i have a list like:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

and i want my dictionary to be:

```
dict = {1:2,3,4,5}
```

is there anyway to do this?

Comment: You want a dictionary or a set?

Comment: well dictionary because thats what it is called in python, i don't know what a set is.

Comment: What's `{1:2,3,4,5}` supposed to be? Is `2,3,4,5` a tuple?

Comment: That's not a valid dictionary in your expected result. It's a weird mash-up between a dictionary and set.

Comment: [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) , read this.. it might help you.

Comment: 2,3,4,5 is just meant to represent different data

Comment: Well, dictionary should have pairs of key and value, you don't parse single values in Dictionary. Can you be more specific about what you want to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a list to a dictionary in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576115/convert-a-list-to-a-dictionary-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want a dictionary with a single key and a list:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]

d = {l[0]:l[1:]}
```

Output:

```
{1: [2, 3, 4, 5]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List = [1,2,3,4,5]

Dict = {List.pop(0):List}
```

output:

```
{1: [2, 3, 4, 5]}
```