# Python 3 lists to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, merge

I have a three lists and I would like to build a dictionary using them:

```
a = [a,b,c]  
b = [1,2,3]  
c = [4,5,6]
```

i expect to have:

```
{'a':1,4, 'b':2,5, 'c':3,6}
```

All I can do now is:

```
{'a':1,'b':2, 'c':3}
```

What should i do?

Comment: The output you expect isn't a valid literal. Do you want the values to be lists? Try searching for that.

Comment: You should correct your creation of list a, did you mean some string literals instead of ,a,b,c?, do you want tuple () or list [] as a value for each key?

Comment: Your expected result does not look like a python dictionary nor any python object.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a list to a dictionary in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576115/convert-a-list-to-a-dictionary-in-python)

Answer (score 5):

You can try this:

```
a = ["a","b","c"] 
b = [1,2,3]  
c = [4,5,6]  

new_dict = {i:[j, k] for i, j, k in zip(a, b, c)}
```

Output:

```
{'b': [2, 5], 'c': [3, 6], 'a': [1, 4]}
```

If you really want a sorted result, you can try this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict()

for i, j, k in zip(a, b, c):
    d[i] = [j, k]
```

Now, you have an OrderedDict object with the keys sorted alphabetically.

Answer (score 3):

check this: [how to zip two lists into new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/map-two-lists-into-a-dictionary-in-python)
i suggest to first zip the b and c lists and then map them into a dictionary again using zip:

```
a = ['a','b','c']
b = [1,2,3]
c = [4,5,6]
vals = zip(b,c)
d = dict(zip(a,vals))
print(d)
```

Comment: Thank you nio. This is exactly what i needed.
In fact i have tried already to zip 2 list but i got <zip object at 0x00689A58>.
and I could not print them. Funny is it i working all together.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ['a','b','c']  
b = [1,2,3]  
c = [4,5,6] 

result = { k:v  for k,*v in zip(a,b,c)}
```

**RESULT**

```
print(result)
```

Comment: Can you explain your code and why it solves the issue? *Code only* answers are often not that helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
Promotion_or_Not = "Yes","Yes","No","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","No","Yes","No"
Nopay_leave_or_not ="No","No","Yes","Yes","No","Yes","Yes","No","Yes","No"

Last_year_evaluation = "Good","Bad","Moderate","Good","Moderate","Moderate","Good","Bad","Good","Moderate"


mydict = {'Promotion_or_Not': [Promotion_or_Not],'Nopay_leave_or_not': [Nopay_leave_or_not], 'Last_year_evaluation':[Last_year_evaluation] }
print(mydict)
```

Comment: This ans not adressing the qus at all. You just statically assign variable instead of following the example, provided in the qus.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34119868)