# How to write an indexed loop over a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have the following code that takes a string biology_score and after splitting it, converts it into a string ('b'). The desired output is to produce what I have constructed manually below (a list of users with their corresponding scores)

I would be interested in the most efficient way to construct a for loop to achieve this with a list. Note: I am aware that the best way to approach this would be a dictionary, but these purposes I want to use a list.

**Code:**

```
biology_score="user1,30,user2,60,user3,99"
print(biology_score[1]) #for testing purposes
b=biology_score.split(",")
print(b) #prints lists
print(b[2]) #prints element in index 2 in the list

#desired output
print(b[0],"scored",b[1])
print(b[2],"scored",b[3])
print(b[4],"scored",b[5])

#create a for loop to do the above
```

**Required answer**

1. The most elegant solution (for loop to produce the above by looping through the list)
2. The easiest/quickest method to convert the string to a dictionary, using the least number of steps, and then achieving the same output (user: score)

Comment: Your second question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576115/convert-a-list-to-a-dictionary-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for:

```
biology_score="user1,30,user2,60,user3,99"
print(biology_score[1]) #for testing purposes
b=biology_score.split(",")
biology_dict = {}

for i in range(0, len(b), 2):  #looks only at even indices
    print(b[i],"scored",b[i+1])
    biology_dict[b[i]] = b[i+1]
```

Comment: Sorry, ignore previous comment - this is beautiful. works fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If this is what you need.

```
#create a for loop to do the above
for i in range(0,len(b)-1,2):
  print(b[i],"scored",b[i+1])
```

Note: Python versions <3.6 does not support element orders. So, when you go with `dict`, the order might not be retained.

Answer (score 1):

One of the options is to use dictionary

If the iterables are of uneven length, missing values are filled-in with fillvalue

```
import itertools    
d = dict(itertools.zip_longest(*[iter(biology_score.split(","))] * 2, 
fillvalue=""))

for k, v in d.items():
    print(k,'scored', v)
```

Comment: can you please clearly explain the line d = dict(itertools.zip_longest(*[iter(biology_score.split(","))] * 2,    Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `grouper` recipe from the itertools module:

```
import itertools
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return itertools.zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

Then:

```
for user, score in grouper(b, 2):
    print(user, 'scored', score)
```

To make a dictionary:

```
dictionary = dict(grouper(b, 2))
for user, score in dictionary.items():
    print(user, 'scored', score)
```

Or use an OrderedDict if the original order of the items should be preserverd.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly a rewrite of @chngzm's answer, and it's probably unsuitable for your teaching purposes, but using a generator is quite nice:

```
def user_scores(scores):
  s = scores.split(",")
  for idx in range(0, len(s), 2):
    yield s[idx], s[idx+1]

biology_score="user1,30,user2,60,user3,99"

for user, score in user_scores(biology_score):
  print("{0} scored {1}".format(user, score))

biology_dict = dict(s for s in user_scores(biology_score))
for user in biology_dict:
  print("{0} scored {1}".format(user, biology_dict[user]))
```

Answer (score 0):

One Pythonic way to get the desired result is to use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
biology_score = "user1,30,user2,60,user3,99"
values = biology_score.split(',')
print(dict(zip(values[::2], values[1::2])))
# {'user2': '60', 'user3': '99', 'user1': '30'}
```

If you want integer scores, you can use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
print(dict(zip(values[::2], map(int, values[1::2]))))
# {'user2': 60, 'user3': 99, 'user1': 30}
```