# return a key value pair fro a list of lists in python

Tags: python

I have a list of lists: `myList = [['make', 'Ford'], ['model', 'Mustang'], ['year', 1964]]`
Would like to return a dictionary with key, value pairs `dict={make:'Ford',model:'Mustang',......}`

```
d ={}
for row in myList:
  for col in row:
    d[col]=row[1]
```

This returns the first key value pair correct `{'make':'Ford','Ford':'Ford','model':'Mustang','Mustang':'Mustang'...}` but then it repeats the second value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a list to a dictionary in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576115/convert-a-list-to-a-dictionary-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the built-in [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) funtion

```
myList = [['make', 'Ford'], ['model', 'Mustang'], ['year', 1964]]
d = dict(myList)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d={}
for row in myList:
    d[row[0]] = row[1]
```

This is how you’d do this if you want to use loops, but you can also just `d = dict(myList)` to cast the list to a dict.

Comment: Thanks.  This helped me understand what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
myList = [['make', 'Ford'], ['model', 'Mustang'], ['year', 1964]]
final_dict = {a:b for a, b in myList}
```

Output:

```
{'make': 'Ford', 'model': 'Mustang', 'year': 1964}
```