# Python: Create dictionary with list index number as key and list element as value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

All the questions I've seen do the exact opposite of what I want to do:

Say I have a list:

```
lst = ['a','b','c']
```

I am looking to make a dictionary where the key is the element number (starting with 1 instead of 0) and the list element is the value. Like this:

```
{1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c'}
```

But for a long list. I've read a little about enumerate() but everything I've seen has used the list element as the key instead.

I found this:

```
dict = {tuple(key): idx for idx, key in enumerate(lst)}
```

But that produces:

```
{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
```

... which is the opposite of what I want. And, also in a weird notation that is confusing to someone new to Python.

Advice is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4576128/7062327

Comment: The "weird notation" is called a dictionary comprehension.  Comprehensions are super handy, and if you'll see a lot of them.  Here's a decent place to start reading: https://www.smallsurething.com/list-dict-and-set-comprehensions-by-example/

Comment: @PatrickHaugh So is dictionary comprehension necessary to do certain things or is it just more concise? As in, can those sort of things be written as normal for loops? If that question makes sense.

Comment: @hexaneandheels No, you can always unroll the comprehension into a `for` loop.  It's for brevity and clarity.  Here's a document that touches on the Rationale behind them, and includes some more examples: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/#rationale

Answer (score 13):

`enumerate` has a `start` keyword argument so you can count from whatever number you want.  Then just pass that to `dict`

```
dict(enumerate(lst, start=1))
```

You could also write a dictionary comprehension

```
{index: x for index, x in enumerate(lst, start=1)}
```

Comment: Is `O(n)` the time complexity for the first method?

Answer (score 1):

By default enumerate start from 0 , but you can set by this value by second argument which is `start` , You can add +1 to every iterator if you want to start from 1 instead of zero  :

```
print({index+1:value for index,value in enumerate(lst)})
```

output:

```
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
```

Above dict comprehension is same as :

```
dict_1={}
for index,value in enumerate(lst):
    dict_1[index+1]=value
print(dict_1)
```

Comment: Instead of adding 1 you can use the `start` argument of `enumerate`, which indicates what number the enumeration should start at.

Answer (score 0):

Using Dict Comprehension and enumerate

```
print({x:y for x,y in enumerate(lst,1)})
```

{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}

Using Dict Comprehension , zip and range-

```
print({x:y for x,y in zip(range(1,len(lst)+1),lst)})
```

{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}

Answer (score 0):

I think the below code should help.

```
my_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
my_index = []
my_dict = {}

for i in range(len(my_list)): 
    my_index.append(i+1)

for key in my_index: 
    for value in my_list: 
        my_dict[key] = value
```