# Taking dictionary/list, and mapping to dataframe with x number of matching columns

Tags: python, pandas, parsing

I have a table that contains 2 columns.

```
     Column 1 | Column 2     
----------------------------
unique_number | '123 Main St. Suite 100 Chicago, IL'
```

I've been exploring address parsing using https://parserator.datamade.us/api-docs and ideally would like to parse the address, and put the results into new columns.

```
import usaddress
addr='123 Main St. Suite 100 Chicago, IL'
```

Two options for returning parsed results, and I plan on using whichever is easier to add to a dataframe:

1. `usaddress.parse(addr)` The parse method will split your address string into components, and
   label each component. (returns list)
2. `usaddress.tag(addr)` The tag method will try to be a little smarter it will merge consecutive components, strip commas, & return an address type (returns ordered list)

There are 26 different tags available for an address using this parser.

However, Not all addresses will contain all of these tags.

I need to grab the full address for each row, parse it, map the parsed results to each matching column in that same row.

[What the tag data looks like using from_records (index isn't exactly ideal)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibDKK.png)

[What the parse data looks like using from_records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eOwz.png)

I can't quite figure out how to logic of row by row calculations and mapping results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Super late in posting this solution, but wanted to in case anyone else ran into the same problem

Address csv file headings:

```
name, address
```

Imports:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
import itertools
import usaddress

def address_func(address):
    try:
        return usaddress.tag(address)
    except:
        return [{'AddressConverstion':'Error'}]

# import file
file = pd.read_excel('addresses.xlsx')

# apply function
file['tag_response'] = file['Full Address'].apply(address_func)

# copy values to new column
file['tags'] = file.apply(lambda row: row['tag_response'][0], axis=1)

# dump json
tags_combined = json.dumps(list(file['tags']))

# create dataframe of parsed info
df_parsed = pd.io.json.json_normalize(json.loads(tags_combined))

# merge dataframes on index
merged = file.join(df_parsed)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, create a column of json responses from the parsing service

```
df['json_response'] = df['address'].apply(usaddress.pars)
```

Next, combine all the jsons into a single json string

```
json_combined = json.dumps(list(df['json_response']))
```

Finally parse the combined json to a dataframe (after parsing the json string)

```
df_parsed = pd.io.json.json_normalize(json.loads(json_combined))
```

Now you should have a structured dataframe with all required columns which you can `df.join` with your original dataframe to produce a single unified dataset.

Just a note, depending on the structure of the returned json, you may need to pass further arguments to the `[pandas.io.json.json_normalize](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) function. The example on the linked page is a good starting point.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Definitely in the right direction.
I'm running into an issue on the last line `list object jas no attribute values`
[view of the data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v9lkcgxqw3beda3/Screenshot%202017-12-05%2012.00.46.png?dl=0)

Comment: It's difficult to know exactly what's going on without looking at the actual outputs, but it appears that the function `usaddress.pars` isn't returning a JSON but rather a list. You'll need to convert the list pairs to a dict that has an key-value pair structure similar to a JSON. Check out this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576115/convert-a-list-to-a-dictionary-in-python).