# Turning list into dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have list:

```
['Location: NY',
 'price: 11103 USD', 
 'Year: 2018', 
 'Model: Golf VII',
'Security',
'Airbag']
```

how do I turn it into dictionary?
I'm using different type of list than what is described in problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576115/convert-a-list-to-a-dictionary-in-python).
Also **some list elements are empty**, I need to omit them in final dictionary.

Comment: Where is your [mre],where is your problem, what did you try?

Comment: Suppose, you have a list of pairs, e.g. `[('Location', 'NY'), ...]`. Do you know how to get this list and how to get from there to a dict?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a list to a dictionary in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576115/convert-a-list-to-a-dictionary-in-python)

Comment: It's not duplicate, check that already and tried all of that as well..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use do a dict comperhension for this application,

My solution is similar to that of @vahdet's answer, but this solution will take care of multiple spaces that may occur in key or value.

```
l = ['Location: NY',
 'price: 11103 USD', 
 'Year: 2018', 
 'Model: Golf VII']

dict( (x.split(':')[0].strip(),  x.split(':')[1].strip()) for x in l )
```

You can make use of this same dict comprehension to handle invalid items in the list by checking whether `:` exists in the list or not like this and adding the key-value only if the item is valid,

```
l = ['Location: NY',
     'price: 11103 USD',
     'Year: 2018',
     'Model: Golf VII',
     'Security',
     'Airbag']

print(dict((x.split(':')[0].strip(), x.split(':')[1].strip()) for x in l if ':' in x))
```

Comment: One liner solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If your pattern always like you depict, you can `split(': ')` your items

```
my_list = ['Location: NY', 'price: 11103 USD', 'Year: 2018', 'Model: Golf VII']
my_dict = { i.split(': ')[0] : i.split(': ')[1] for i in my_list }
```

**ADDITION FOR THE EMPTY VALUES:**

You can also extract your logic into a function and make some other controls (trimming, null values etc), and still use dictionary comprehension as follows:

```
def str_to_keyval(inp, separator=':'):
  # to list
  li = inp.split(separator) if (separator in inp) else [inp, '']
  # strip elements
  return [i.strip() for i in li]

my_list = [
  'Location: NY',
  'price: 11103 USD',
  'Year: 2018',
  'Model: Golf VII',
  'Security',
  'Airbag'
]

my_dict = { str_to_keyval(i)[0] : str_to_keyval(i)[1] for i in my_list }
```

You can change the presentation of null values (ignore their keys, or denote with an empty string etc.) through editing the first line of `str_to_keyval` function in the example. As it is, it gives empty string as missing values.

Comment: what if I have empty elements in list...which is reason why all of this is not working initially

Comment: So, how *empty* are they? Still have keys? Totally empty strings?

Comment: I've edited my question. Keys are there but values are missing. Separator is missing as well for those empty elements.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the first thing you'll need to do is loop over every item in the list. This is pretty easy using a for loop

```
for item in lst:
    # do stuff with the item
```

After that, you'll need to separate the item into a key and a value. The keys and values are already separated by a colon and a space, so I would just split the string using that.

```
for item in lst:
    split_item = item.split(": ")
    key = split_item[0]
    value = split_item[1]
    # then you need to add the key and item to the dictionary
```

Adding the value is pretty simple. Just define the new value:

```
dictionary = {} # just to initialize the dictionary, if you already initialized it, don't do this
for item in lst:
    split_item = item.split(": ")
    key = split_item[0]
    value = split_item[1]
    dictionary[key] = value
```

That's it

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `split` function to get the parts of each string to create your dictionary reference:

```
arr = ['Location: NY', 'price: 11103 USD', 'Year: 2018', 'Model: Golf VII']
dict = {}

for i in range(0, len(arr)):
    key, value = arr[i].split(": ")
    dict[key] = value

print(dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

With this list:

```
mylist = ['Location: NY',
 'price: 11103 USD', 
 'Year: 2018', 
 'Model: Golf VII']
```

Try following code:

```
mydict = {}
for l in mylist: 
    a,b = l.split(': ')
    mydict[a] = b
print(mydict)
```

Output:

```
{'Year': '2018', 'Model': 'Golf VII', 'price': '11103 USD', 'Location': 'NY'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple comprehension with `dict`:

```
my_list = ['Location: NY', 'price: 11103 USD', 'Year: 2018', 'Model: Golf VII']
result = dict(i.split(': ') for i in my_list)
```

Output:

```
{'Location': 'NY', 'price': '11103 USD', 'Year': '2018', 'Model': 'Golf VII'}
```

Comment: Thats giving me ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #4 has length 1; 2 is required

Comment: @Harvey please post the input you are using

Comment: I've posted update several minutes after I created question.

Answer (score -3):

```
a=['Location: NY',
 'price: 11103 USD',
 'Year: 2018',
 'Model: Golf VII']

   b=[]

   x={}

   for i in range(len(a)):

       b.append(a[i].split(':'))


   for i in range(len(b)):

       for j in range(len(b[i])):

          x[b[i][0]]=b[i][1]

   print(x)
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!