# Regex to split by semicolon and comma, except in some circustances

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that are comma delimited, however, some of the strings are datetimes which are delimited as well with semicolons and commas. For example:

```
'CreationTime: 1/12/2021 6:21:07 PM, LastAccessTime: 1/12/2021 6:21:05 PM, LastWriteTime: 1/12/2021 6:21:05 PM, ChangeTime: 1/12/2021 6:21:07 PM, FileAttributes: N, AllocationSize: 4,096, EndOfFile: 3,115, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False, IndexNumber: 0x3000000032494, EaSize: 0, Access: Generic Read, Position: 0, Mode: Sequential Access, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, AlignmentRequirement: Word'
```

Clearly, `CreationTime: 1/12/2021 6:21:07 PM` is the first string I want parsed, and I also want to separate `CreationTime` from it's attribute `1/12/2021 6:21:07 PM` while doing that for every item separated by a `,`, with a header and attribute separated by a `:`.

To make things more complicated, some headers have multiple attributes

```
Mode: Sequential Access, Synchronous IO Non-Alert
```

So both `Sequential Access, Synchronous IO Non-Alert` are two attributes belonging to `Mode:` but they are not to be confused with the comma delimiter for the next header that comes after `AlignmentRequirement:`.

### Question

How can I parse my example string so it returns a header and attribute (e.g. `Mode` and `Sequential Access, Synchronous IO Non-Alert`) given that their are semicolons and commas in the attributes themselves.

Comment: Do you have list of headers/keys in advance?

Comment: Where is the question OP?

Comment: @buran, Nope. They are all in the string itself, directly preceding the semicolon. And I need to do this for thousands of different strings with different headers so I need to do this adaptively.

Comment: @qräbnö, edited with a more specific question.

Comment: I couldn't understand the down vote, sorry. My answer gives you what you need. If you want something different, you should make it more explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.split) to split the string. Put parentheses around `[A-Za-z]+` to return the matched part as well (these will become the dictionary keys later). Remove the first element of the list (an empty string) using a slice: `[1:]`. Finally, convert the list into a dictionary using [any of the methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4576115/967621). I chose to do so using an iterator.

```
import re
s = 'CreationTime: 1/12/2021 6:21:07 PM, LastAccessTime: 1/12/2021 6:21:05 PM, LastWriteTime: 1/12/2021 6:21:05 PM, ChangeTime: 1/12/2021 6:21:07 PM, FileAttributes: N, AllocationSize: 4,096, EndOfFile: 3,115, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False, IndexNumber: 0x3000000032494, EaSize: 0, Access: Generic Read, Position: 0, Mode: Sequential Access, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, AlignmentRequirement: Word'
it = iter(re.split(r'([A-Za-z]+):', s)[1:])
dct = dict(zip(it, it))
print(dct)
# {'CreationTime': ' 1/12/2021 6:21:07 PM, ', 'LastAccessTime': ' 1/12/2021 6:21:05 PM, ', 'LastWriteTime': ' 1/12/2021 6:21:05 PM, ', 'ChangeTime': ' 1/12/2021 6:21:07 PM, ', 'FileAttributes': ' N, ', 'AllocationSize': ' 4,096, ', 'EndOfFile': ' 3,115, ', 'NumberOfLinks': ' 1, ', 'DeletePending': ' False, ', 'Directory': ' False, ', 'IndexNumber': ' 0x3000000032494, ', 'EaSize': ' 0, ', 'Access': ' Generic Read, ', 'Position': ' 0, ', 'Mode': ' Sequential Access, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, ', 'AlignmentRequirement': ' Word'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```py
t = 'CreationTime: 1/12/2021 6:21:07 PM, LastAccessTime: 1/12/2021 6:21:05 PM, LastWriteTime: 1/12/2021 6:21:05 PM, ChangeTime: 1/12/2021 6:21:07 PM, FileAttributes: N, AllocationSize: 4,096, EndOfFile: 3,115, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False, IndexNumber: 0x3000000032494, EaSize: 0, Access: Generic Read, Position: 0, Mode: Sequential Access, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, AlignmentRequirement: Word'
# re.split with lookahead, then split first ": "
dict([x.split(': ', maxsplit=1) for x in re.split(r', (?=[^\s:]+\:)', t)])
>>>
{'CreationTime': '1/12/2021 6:21:07 PM',
 'LastAccessTime': '1/12/2021 6:21:05 PM',
 'LastWriteTime': '1/12/2021 6:21:05 PM',
 'ChangeTime': '1/12/2021 6:21:07 PM',
 'FileAttributes': 'N',
 'AllocationSize': '4,096',
 'EndOfFile': '3,115',
 'NumberOfLinks': '1',
 'DeletePending': 'False',
 'Directory': 'False',
 'IndexNumber': '0x3000000032494',
 'EaSize': '0',
 'Access': 'Generic Read',
 'Position': '0',
 'Mode': 'Sequential Access, Synchronous IO Non-Alert',
 'AlignmentRequirement': 'Word'}
```

Comment: I really don't understand the downvote. Please upvote if you like. thx.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote either. This solved my problem perfectly. My question got downvoted even though it has two correct answers, so obviously someone doesn't like regex very much.