# create dictionary from given list in python

Tags: python

I have a python list , and I want to create a dictionary with word as a key and number as a value. what is the efficient way of doing this. Here is the my code:

```
['a',100,'b',200,'c',300,'d',400]
```

I want to convert it into dictionary like `{'a':100,'b':200,'c':300,'d':400}`
please help me.

Comment: you could always try a `for` loop

Comment: Can this help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576115/convert-key1-val1-key2-val2-to-a-dict

Comment: I have tried following code  
my_list = ['a',100,'b',200,'c',300,'d',400]
v1 = []
v2 = []

for chr in my_list:
    if type(chr) == chr.isalpha():
        v1.append(chr)
    else:
        v2.append(chr)

ans = zip(v1,v2)
print(ans)

Answer (score 0):

Apply your list for this convert function.

```
def Convert(lst):
    res_dct = {lst[i]: lst[i + 1] for i in range(0, len(lst), 2)}
    return res_dct
    

lst = ['a', 100, 'b', 200, 'c', 300]
print(Convert(lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop through the list, and add to dictionary as key element at index, and as value element at index + 1.
I write sample code for you to understand easier, I didn't use any builtin methods for conversion, I don't is there any methods for what you want, but there is always solution.
Code:

```
list1 = ['a',100,'b',200,'c',300,'d',400]

dict1 = { }

# this is for loup which is used for "conversion"
for i in range(0, len(list1), 2):
    dict1[list1[i]] = list1[i+1]
    
for i in dict1:
    print("Key : " + i + " Value : " + str(dict1[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Pythonic way:

```
>>> lst = ['a',100,'b',200,'c',300,'d',400]
>>> dict(zip(lst[::2], lst[1::2]))
{'d': 400, 'c': 300, 'a': 100, 'b': 200}
```

Comment: @DheerajSurwase if like my solution you can accept it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

That's just one efficient line

```
{ key: value for key, value in zip(x[::2], x[1::2]) } # x is the input list
```

**Explanation:**

- `x[::2]` - takes all even index elements of the list: slice the list at zero through the end with step of 2 (`['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`)
- `x[1::2]` - takes all odd index elements of the list: slice the list at index 1 through the end with step of 2 (`[100, 200, 300, 400]`)
- `zip(x[::2], x[1::2])` - extracts a tuple of elements from both the inputs (`[('a',100), ('b', 200), ('c', 300), ('d', 400)]`)
- `{ key: value for key, value in zip(...) }` - iterates on the `(key=even elements, value=odd elements)` tuples and creates the dictionary