# Python: Convert multiple list into an array of dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

Imagine that you have the following list.

```
name = ['bob', 'kate', 'john']
age = [35, 12, 57]
gender = ["Male", "Female", "Male"]
```

How do you convert it to an array of dictionary?

```
[
  {
    "name": "bob"
    "age": 35
    "gender": "Male"
  },
  {
    "name": "kate"
    "age": 12
    "gender": "Female"
  },
  {
    "name": "john"
    "age": 57
    "gender": "Male"
  }
]
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Do you know how to make a dictionary from a list? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597166/make-dictionary-from-list-with-python.  Then, use `yourArray.append(theDict)`

Answer (score 3):

Using [**zip**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704860/zip-lists-in-python) ,[**List comprehension**](http://carlgroner.me/Python/2011/11/09/An-Introduction-to-List-Comprehensions-in-Python.html)

**Code:**

```
name = ['bob', 'kate', 'john']
age = [35, 12, 57]
gender = ["Male", "Female", "Male"]

dic= [ {"name":val[0], "age":val[1], "gender":val[2]} for val in zip(name, age, gender)]
```

**Output:**

```
[{'name':'bob','age':35,'gender':'Male'},
 {'name':'kate','age':12,'gender':'Female'},
 {'name':'john','age':57,'gender':'Male'}]
```

Comment: This outputs
`[set(['name:bob,age:35,gender:Male']), set(['name:kate,age:12,gender:Female']), set(['name:john,age:57,gender:Male'])]`

Answer (score 3):

A generic method which works for any number of lists with customizable field names

```
import pprint
def make_complex(**kwargs):
    return [dict(zip(kwargs.keys(), a)) for a in zip(*kwargs.values())]

name = ['bob', 'kate', 'john']
age = [35, 12, 57]
gender = ["Male", "Female", "Male"]

l = make_complex(name=name, age=age, gender=gender)
pprint.pprint(l)

l = make_complex(user=name, year=age, sex=gender)
pprint.pprint(l)
```

output:

```
[{'age': 35, 'gender': 'Male', 'name': 'bob'},
 {'age': 12, 'gender': 'Female', 'name': 'kate'},
 {'age': 57, 'gender': 'Male', 'name': 'john'}]
[{'sex': 'Male', 'user': 'bob', 'year': 35},
 {'sex': 'Female', 'user': 'kate', 'year': 12},
 {'sex': 'Male', 'user': 'john', 'year': 57}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a simple loop it would look something like:

```py
name = ['bob', 'kate', 'john']
age = [35, 12, 57]
gender = ["Male", "Female", "Male"]

list=[]

for i in range(len(name)):
  temp={}
  temp['name']=name[i]
  temp['age']=age[i]
  temp['gender']=gender[i]
  list.append(temp)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a list comprehension and itertools

```
import itertools    

d = [{'name': n, 'age': a, 'gender': g} for n, a, g in itertools.izip(name, age, gender)]
```

Comment: Agree with the variable names `n, a, g`

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension.

```
In [3]: [{"name":n,"age":a,"gender":g} for n,a,g in zip(name, age, gender)]
Out[3]:
[{'age': 35, 'gender': 'Male', 'name': 'bob'},
 {'age': 12, 'gender': 'Female', 'name': 'kate'},
 {'age': 57, 'gender': 'Male', 'name': 'john'}]
```

or,

```
In [5]: [dict(zip(['name','age','gender'], t)) for t in zip(name, age, gender)]
Out[5]:
[{'age': 35, 'gender': 'Male', 'name': 'bob'},
 {'age': 12, 'gender': 'Female', 'name': 'kate'},
 {'age': 57, 'gender': 'Male', 'name': 'john'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Go for this.

```
name = ['bob', 'kate', 'john']
age = [35, 12, 57]
gender = ["Male", "Female", "Male"]
keys = [name, age, gender] #If there are more data to be added just change this one place

def get_var_name(var):
    for k, v in list(globals().iteritems()):
        if v is var:
            return k

d = []
for i in range(len(keys[0])):
    d.append({})
    for key in keys:
       d[i][get_var_name(key)] = key[i] 

print d
```

Or use dict comprehension to avoid inner loop

```
d = []
for i in range(len(name)):
    d.append({get_var_name(key):key[i] for key in keys})
print d
```

To make it one liner go combining dict comprehension inner and list comprehension outer

```
print [{get_var_name(key):key[i] for key in keys} for i in range(len(keys[0]))]
```